# Why am I able to change a string constant in C?

Tags: c, pointers

In C when you define a string using a char pointer (technically you are defining a pointer variable), it creates an array of the characters in a read-only segment of memory, then returns a pointer to it. That means you should not be able to modify it since it is a constant. If you wanted to modify it you should use a char array instead or use malloc.

But for some reason I am actually able to change the string, how is this even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // The string "Hello" is a read-only literal (formally its type is const char[5])
    char * msg = "Hello";

    msg = "New string"; // why / how does this work?

    printf("%s \n", msg); // New string
}
```

But at the same time this does not work  (which makes sense)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char * msg = "Hello";

    *(msg + 1) = 'a'; // Error: segmentation fault
    *(msg + 1) = "a"; // Error: segmentation fault

    printf("%s \n", msg);
}
```

Comment: You did not modify the string. You only modified the *pointer* that points to that string. If you don't want that, use `char * const msg = "Hello";` Then your compiler will throw a warning on attempting to modify the pointer.

Comment: *Do not try and assign the string. That's impossible. Instead only try to realize the truth.There is no string. Then you'll see, that it is not the string that is assigned, it is only a pointer.*

Comment: Yes, I know that there is no such thing as strings. There just seems to be some kind of magic going on with `msg = "New string"` that I am not seeing.

Comment: *`The expression msg = "New string" actually does 2 things under the hood. 1) it allocates new space in memory, then puts the new string literal there and 2) it changes the msg to point to the new place in memory`* - no it does not. It only assigns `msg` with the address of string literal. It does not allocate or place anything. Your assumptions are wrong and will give you many programming problems in the future.,

Comment: `It only assigns msg with the address of string literal` - but this string literal how... it has to be put in memory at some point in time and it has to have an address, right? When was it put there? Who put it there?

Comment: This beginner FAQ might be a good place to start: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849)

Comment: Note: I upvoted the question, because, once again, I have the feeling the question is victim of the usual confusion between a bad question, and a question that shows a misconception from the author. Yes, this question shows that author doesn't fully understand what pointers and strings are. But is that not the point of a question? There is a difference between "your question is bad, and should not appear in SO", and "your question contains bad code, and bad understanding of some notions". Downvoting should mean "I think this question hasn't any place in SO". I think it has.

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello"` and `"New string"` are string literals stored somewhere in the memory.

```
char * msg = "Hello";
```

Assigns pointer `msg` with the reference (address) of the first character of the string literal.

```
msg = "New string";
```

Replaces the `msg` pointer previously assigned value. It **does not** modify the previously assigned string literal - only modifies the pointer `msg`.

Second example

```
 *(msg + 1) = 'a';
```

Modifies the string literal - and in C language it is an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that `msg = "New string"` allocates new memory for the "New string"

Comment: @MartinZeltin no  - your assumption is wrong

Comment: Please explain how?

Comment: @MartinZeltin String literal have static storage duration. For your level of C knowledge simply assume that are always allocated and existing

Comment: The new string has to be stored somewhere, so how does it work then? What happens to the old string that was in memory?

Comment: @MartinZeltin Nothing - it is there for the whole program lifetime. It is like home on the street. It is there. You can use its address, but you cant modify it

Comment: What do you mean it is there. How did it get there? When was it put there? It was not malloc'ated there?

Comment: @MartinZeltin Once upon (not a so distant) time, you could even do this ``printf("hello\n"); "hello\n"[1]='A'; print("hello\n");`` and it compiled (it still does, this is legal C), and at run time, printed "hello" and "hAllo". ``"hello\n"`` is just a constant pointer to some chars. Nowaday it would fail at runtime, because those chars are in a protected segment. But the meaning is still the same. ``"hello"`` is just a constant pointer, to a statically filled area containing letters h,e,l,l,o. (or containing them as long as nobody change them. Which is protected nowadays on most machine)

Comment: My head is going to explode. When you say `those chars are in a protected segment... "hello" is just a constant pointer, to a statically filled area containing letters h,e,l..` - how did this constant "hello" get into the memory? I did not call malloc for it...

Comment: @MartinZeltin No, it was not malloc'ated. It is not in the heap. No more than the code itself is. No more than other constants. No more than initial values of arrays. No more than global or static variables. This is static data. In assembly, just a label with some datas (once upon a time, mixed up with the code. Nowadays, in separated segments, but yet, it is still the same "allocation" principle)

Comment: That ``"hello\n"[1]='A';`` is supposed to make you head explode, that being said :-). It is an heresy. But a legal one (although less fun nowadays, since memory protection won't let it run). It would help if you know some assembly language. In assembly, what you do in reality, is just a slight short cut to just enumerating the bytes in the code. In x86, saying "MOV AL, 8" is just a short cut to bytes ``0xB0 0x08``. And you also have pseudo-instructions. Saying ".DB 4,5,6" is bytes "0x04 0x05 0x06". And labels. Prefixing a line with a ``label:`` means that, from now on ``label`` is a shortcut

Comment: ... to address (that is number of bytes from the beginning so far, plus an offset). So, allocating static memory, is just inserting some bytes that are not code somewhere in the middle of that. Of course, then you need to be careful to never try to execute that part of the memory. A compiler does that very well. Plus, nowadays, memory is segmented. So you don't really put the ".DB" parts in the middle of the code (in some segment, it is impossible to run things. In some other, impossible to write, ...).

Comment: But, well, even with segments, static memory is still the same: just some data in the program alongside the code, loaded in the same time the code is. But for segmentation, there is no difference between the static memory (of global variables, constant strings, etc.) and the static memory of the code you are running. You wouldn't say that your code was "malloc'ated", would you?

Comment: @MartinZeltin Everything in a computer program is of course allocated somewhere. A lot of things are allocated at link-time, when a decision is taken if a certain item needs to be part of the linked binary or not. String literals are allocated at link-time, in read-only memory. Not to be confused with stack or heap allocation which happen in run-time. And heap allocation only happens when the programmer explicitly requests it with malloc or similar function calls.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now at last, thank you guys!

Comment: @MartinZeltin it is there because it was placed there before the `main` function was called. How it is done depends on OS, hardware and implementation. It will differ in the bare metal system and hosted one. It will differ between hardware architectures - for example, AVR & ARM will do it a completely different way, as they have different memory bus architecture

Comment: So when my program compiles and starts it scans all the string literals in my code, puts them in my program and when I call `msg = "New string"` it goes - "Ah, I know this string and its address, I wil point to it now". Right?

Comment: @MartinZeltin Compiler has to "scan" everything in your C source code :). How the program starts is up to implementation and is not important from your point of view.

Comment: `not important from your point of view` - I think it is important because I needed to know how the string literal got there in the first place.

Comment: @MartinZeltin you do not need this information. C standard does not say anything about it as it is not needed when you write the code. You need to understand what the pointer is not how the assignment is done under the hood

Answer (score 0):

Your "EDIT" explanation is false. Or not exact.

```c
char * msg = "Hello";
```

As you said, keep a place in the stack for a pointer (in practice, 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the architecture), and also, 6 bytes in an area of the memory for constants (one for each of the 5 letters h, e, l, l, o, and another for the terminal '\0').

So `msg` is a variable (a classical, read/write variable) whose value can be changed.
And `"hello"` is a constant pointer.
And, as you said, at first, value of `msg` is the constant pointer `"hello"`, that points to a constant area containing letters h,e,l,l,o,'\0'.

```c
msg = "New string";
```

Does not allocate anything at all. I mean, not at run time. At compilation time, the simple fact that "New string" is mentionned somewhere in the code, created another constant (that exist as soon as the program is ran, not when it encounter this line of code) containing letters, N,e,w,' ',s,t,r,i,n,g,'\0'.

"New string" is just a constant. As 12 is. A constant pointer. Pointing to a constant area of the memory (so constant pointer to constant chars).

So all you did in line

```c
msg = "New string";
```

is just changing the value of a variable to another constant.
It would be as `x=12`.

Note that literals `"foo"` are technically constant pointers.
So exactly like

```c
char hello[6]="hello";
```

is

(This is the difference between arrays and pointers: here, `hello` is not a variable. It is a constant. Exactly as 12 is. Or as `"hello"` is. A constant whose value is computed by the compiler, that's its job.)

Note also that I've said that `"hello"` is a constant pointer to constant chars. That is not exact neither. Char pointed by `"hello"` are not constant from the language point of view. They are l-values, as the chars of my array `hello`.

If you try to compile

```c
char hello[6]="hello";
hello="foo";
"hello"="bar";
12=13;
```

It would not compile at all. Even with a warning, it couldn't. Those 3 lines are exactly the same non-sense from the compiler point of view. You can't use a constant as a L-value. The compiler could not know at all where you want to store the right value.

On the other hand, if you try this code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello\n");
    "Hello\n"[1]='a';
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

You don't get a compilation error. Sure, you get a fair warning from the compiler, meaning "ok, I compile it, because it is legal from my point of view. But it will crash if you try to run it".
But here, exactly as `hello` array is a constant, but `hello[1]` can still be modified (that's the whole point of arrays), `"hello"` array is also a constant, but `"hello"[1]` is not, and could be modified, from the language point of view.

Now, since `"hello"` points to a segment of the memory that is not supposed to be modified at run time, you get a segmentation fault.

That is almost recent tho. When I was teaching C (some 10-15 years ago), this code was running perfectly (it prints "Hello" the first time, then "Hallo" the second. You can see why it is a terrible idea from code lisibility: constant `"hello"` is a pointer to an area containing the letters `hallo`). I was using this kind of examples (and many things that we should never do) to illustrate what really are strings literals.
10-15 years ago may seem to be a long time ago. But it is not as if it was before the invention of segments, and segmentation fault. Memory was already segmented back then. Just, not for that.

So, obviously, I am not trying at all to teach you tricks here. But just to understand what string literals are. Just the name of a constant pointer to a char. Like arrays are.

Answer (score 0):

First, while string literals are *supposed* to be immutable, they don't *have* to be stored in a read-only segment.  There have been (and still are) implementations that store string literals in writable segments.

The behavior on trying to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined* - it may work as expected, it may have no effect at all, it may lead to a runtime error.

Storage for string literals is usually allocated when the program is initially loaded (they're usually part of the program image) and are visible over the entire program.  IOW, when you write

```
msg = "New string";
```

the storage for `"New string"` isn't allocated at that point during runtime - it was allocated when the program first started.  You're just setting `msg` to point to that already-allocated memory.

For pointers that point to literals, it's usually a good practice to declare them `const`:

```
const char *msg = "Hello";
```

You can still change `msg` to point to a different string literal:

```
msg = "New string";
```

but if you try to modify the contents of the string itself you'll get a diagnostic during compilation:

```
*msg = 'n'; // *msg is const, compiler will yak
```

Answer (score 0):

> (technically you are defining a pointer variable)

If use the word "technically", you're really raising expectations of technical accuracy.

This:

```
char *msg
```

is a [*pointer declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer).

This:

```
char *msg = "Hello";
```

is a [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) which includes an [initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization) whose initial expression is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal).

The type of the string literal is `char[6]` (it's an array of 6 characters including the terminator). Note that despite the type being non-const,

> String literals are **not modifiable** (...). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined.

and note also that

> ... at translation phase 7, a terminating null character is added to each string literal, and then each literal initializes an unnamed array with static storage duration and length just enough to contain the contents of the string literal plus one for the null terminator.

(both quotes from the link above).

That is,

1. you really *cannot* portably modify a string literal (although UB permits it to work as a platform feature, it's unwise to rely on this), and
2. the storage was allocated at compile time, and the array lasts as long as the program. It definitely is **not** allocated when the initialization is executed at runtime.

So, how can you initialize a pointer with an array? Because arrays easily decay into pointers (to the first element). So, `msg` simply contains the address of the first character, `'H'`.

```
msg = "New string"; // why / how does this work?
```

It works because `msg` is a *mutable* pointer, so you can *mutate* it to point elsewhere. The static array `char[6] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 )` elsewhere in memory is entirely unaffected.

Answer (score -2):

In the first case, you are simply changing the value that the pointer is pointing.

On the second, you are trying to acces a restricted memmory area, so you get the segmentation fault.

That's how pointers work.

Comment: Why is the first not restricted memory area and the second is?

Comment: @MartinZeltin why would it be restricted? It is just a pointer. You can make it point anywhere. The string literal is immutable, not the pointer.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `msg = "New string"` actually creates a new array in memory and then changes the pointer to point to it. Right? I can see that the value of `msg` changes. Does it free up the old string from memory automatically?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it @MartinZeltin

Comment: @kelmi92 - no it does not create any new arrays in the memory

Comment: @MartinZeltin no it doesn't. See other exchanges in comments. Array containing letters "New string" was always there (since the loading of the program) and will always be there (till the program ends). What that line does is just changing the value of the variable msg. msg contained a pointer to an existing area. You change it to a pointer to another already existing area, that's all.

Comment: That line of code is nothing more than ``x=12``. Storing a constant value in a variable, that's all. Type of the variable is different (``char *`` vs ``int``. Both 4 or 8 bytes). Type of the constant also is (obviously, similarly: a ``char *`` vs a ``int`` literal). But that's all. From the compiler point of view "New string" is just a constant, as 12 is. Just a 4 or 8 bytes long constant that could fit in a register or an operand. The constant address of the place where the compiler decided (at compilation time) store letters "New string". Again, it is roughly the same code as ``x=12``.

Comment: @chrslg `Array containing letters "New string" was always there (since the loading of the program) and will always be there (till the program ends).` - This is the part that I did not know / understand before. Thank you for explaining this.